# Implementing an interface in partial generated class (OpenAccess, EntityFramework)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-open-access

I have the following issue. Im using Telerik OpenAccess as my ORM (very similar to Entity Framework), so when I add a Entity to my model, for example "Client", the partial class Client is created (Client.generated.cs). Im trying to implement an interface (IEntity) so I created a new partial class Cilent which implements that interface, and the following error apears:
"'Client' does not implement the interface 'IEntity'... bla bla bla." making reference to the generated class.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you implement _all_ the `IEntity` members in `Client`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suppose that **one or more** of the properties/methods defined in the ***IEntity*** interface **are not implemented** in the ***Client*** class. Double check that all interface members are implemented, check the casing too.

If this doesn't help, please post code snippets in order to assist you further.

Comment: What happened was that one of the methods form IEntity had a "long" return type and in the implementation the retrun type was int. Working tired dont let you see that kind of stuff. Thanks